# Why doesn't GIMP open on Mac OS X10.8.5 work?

Tags: gimp

I recently installed OS X 10.8.5 in my mac book pro. I was using GIMP without any problems with 10.7. NOw I installed GIMP 2.8.14p2 and X Quartz 2.7.7 but it doesn't open. HOw can I get it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm in macOS Mojave 10.4.5 and I had to take Gimp app out of the DMG to make it run. When asked by the system, agree to Open it and it'll work. It won't work if you do it from the .dmg even if you allow to open, it's a matter of permissions. Most probably, you'll want to move it to the Applications folder.

This is an answer to an old question, but it might help people who will come across with it, like I did.

Comment: This worked for me on macOS Sierra 10.12.6.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The most common problem with recent installs of the GIMP on a Mac are permissions problems, just like [this error](http://ipfs.pics/QmesoewXNWjqgvJ3mKVTu8WU4maRiBtEQQuVDdgBu5bBYh). Unlike most commercial program, GIMP is not a signed program.

To fix it, you need to go into the security pannel in your settings and [allow program downloaded from anywhere](http://ipfs.pics/QmNoqiWWQEiPg8B6zhAkobd4pKrhUhSsHx3Fh25YJWXEmC), and not just the signed ones.

Keep in mind that it reduces your computer security a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I am running macMojave version 10.4. When I got this message, I went to system preferences > Security & Privacy > At the bottom of the window was message that said gimp install had been block, but offered a Open any way button. I clicked that button and installation proceeded as expected.